# Can't access wcf wsdl anonymously using https url

Tags: wcf, https, wsdl, anonymous

What I would like to do is have a wcf service be anonymous accessible using a https url.

I have created a WCF in a .net 4.0.  Deployed the wcf on a server that is set up to use HTTPS.  The server's IIS is set to allow anonymous calls.  I can access the WCF's Service.svc's website url and the Service.svc page comes up with no issues.  When I click on the wsdl url link on the Service.svc, I get back either a HTTP 404 error or HTTP 401 error.  The wcf's wsdl virtual directory, (I am guessing), won't allow me to get to the wsdl file.

I have set the serviceMetadata's property httpsGetEnabled to true.
wsHttpBinding's security to transport and the clientCredentialType is set to none.
basicHttpBinding's security to transport and the clientCredentialType is set to none.

Is it absolutely certain, I need to create a certificate?  Because when I use VS2010 in another project and add the WCF as a Service Reference, a pop-up certificate dialog box appears and I click okay and it continues onward.  But it stops when the project can't grab the wsdl flie.

How can I get to the service.svc's wsdl?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you browse to the deployed service endpoint, you'll see a screen that has a link to generating the WSDL. You do need a certificate for SSL -- just create a self-signed one (it's pretty easy). Don't forget to set up your https bindings too for your site in IIS.